# C# - Insert XML Element from String template

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml with the given structure:

```
<ArrayOfElement>
    <Element>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Value>Value1</Value>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Value>Value2</Value>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Value>Value3</Value>
    </Element>
    ...
</ArrayOfElement>
```

And I want to insert another Element with this template (but only if no element with the given ID exists):

```
<Element>
    <ID>$ID$</ID>
    <Value>$VALUE$</Value>
</Element>
```

So my idea was to load the template as `string` and replace `$ID$` and `$VALUE$` by whatever is given. Then I parse this string as a `XmlDocumentFragment`. And then I need to see if an element with this ID is already present and only if none is there I want to insert the new one. 
But I don't know how to find if one exists.

My current approach is:

```
// Load the XML with the ArrayOfElement
var allElements = new XmlDocument();
allElements.Load("file.xml");

// Load the template and insert id and value
var xmlTemplate = File.ReadAllText("template.xml");
var fragment = allElements.CreateDocumentFragment();
fragment.InnerXml = xmlTemplate.Replace("$ID$", _id).Replace("$VALUE$", _value);

// This does not work since it will throw an exception if none is found:
if (allElements.SelectNodes("ArrayOfElement/Element/ID/text() = '" + _id + "'").Count == 0)
{
    allElements.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

Also I really want to use a template file because I actually have more complex scenarios where adding these XML-Tags in C# without a template string would be way to much work.

Comment: You can optimize your approach. Instead of creating a fragment element first and search the Original XML, you can first search the Original XML followed by Creation and Insertion.

Comment: I know, but that does not help me with my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions in XPath must be inside brackets, so rewrite xpath as:

```
if (allElements.SelectNodes("ArrayOfElement/Element/ID[text()='" + _id + "']").Count == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the help of XMLSerialization and Deserialization,

```
public class SerializeDeserialize
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArraofElements")]
        public class ArraofElements
        {
            private List<Element> elm = new List<Element>();

            [XmlElement("Module")]
            public List<Element> Elm
            {
                get { return elm; }
                set { elm = value; }
            }
        }

        public class Element
        {
            [XmlElement("ID")]
            public int id { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Value")]
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        ArraofElements dnl = new ArraofElements();

        public void Serialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var temp = dnl.Elm.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == i);
                if (temp == null)
                    temp = new Element();

                temp.id = i;
                temp.value = "Element " + i;

                dnl.Elm.Add(temp);
            }

            try
            {
                // to Save columnorders to the file
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArraofElements));
                var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");


                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"your path"))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, dnl, ns);
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }

        public void Deserialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"your path"))
                {

                    var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArraofElements));
                    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"your path"))
                    {
                        dnl = (ArraofElements)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

this will work as you expected, try this

Comment: This won't work because as I said I want to use template strings. I actually have much bigger nested XML documents and don't want to write 10 POCOs just for this purpose.

Comment: you just want to validate by ID right before adding it to the file,
this might fix

Comment: just for the time being i have added 10 elements you need to updated the code as per your requirement